# Explicit Cast From Type to Not Implemented Interface Compiles but Fails in Runtime

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting, interface-implementation

I have a class and an interface as follows:

```
internal class DoStuff
{
    public int X { get; }
    public void Do() => WriteLine(X);
    public DoStuff(int X) => this.X = X;
}

internal interface IDoStuff
{
    void Do();
}
```

The class `DoStuff` does not implement the interface `IDoStuff`. Therefore, there does not exist an implicit conversion. However, Visual Studio's Intellisense said that an "explicit conversion did exist". This made sense to me, since if an interface had all the same methods of a class, there shouldn't be a reason why you couldn't cast from the class to the interface. I logically inferred that the only reason you could specifically implement an interface in type declaration was for explicit implementation.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719263/22141420), which claimed it was not possible. However, it was written in 2011, and so I assumed that C# had changed since then. C# 5.0 was released in 2012, a year later, and I was on C# 11.0. So, to test my theory, I attempted to create and run the following C# (.NET 6 *top-level* code):

```
// Program.cs:

using static System.Console;

DoStuff  d = new(2);
IDoStuff i = (IDoStuff)d;
i.Do();

return;
```

The code compiled fine, but when I tried to run it, it threw an `InvalidCastException` on the 3rd line:

> `System.InvalidCastException`: Unable to cast object of type `DoStuff` to type `IDoStuff`.

This doesn't make sense. Was the linked post still correct after all?

If so, I have three questions.

1. Why does the C# compiler not throw a build error if the cast was never going to succeed anyway?
2. Why is casting to not implemented interfaces from classes with functions of the same name still not supported in C#? What's the holdup?
3. I vaguely remember reading somewhere that it is possible to explicitly cast between different classes with identical elements. Is this true? If so, what is the difference?

If not, why then is the cast not working?

Here is the full combined code:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WfAHC4

```
using static System.Console;

DoStuff @do = new(2);
IDoStuff iDo = (IDoStuff)@do;
WriteLine("a");
iDo.Do();
WriteLine("b");
ReadKey(true);

internal class DoStuff
{
    public int X { get; }
    public void Do() => WriteLine(X);
    public DoStuff(int X) => this.X = X;
}

internal interface IDoStuff
{
    void Do();
}
```

Comment: `This made sense to me,` no, this doesn't make sense. Just because a type has methods with the same name or signature as another doesn't mean it inherits or implements that other type. Or that the methods are related in any way. `What's the holdup` none. This simply isn't supported in any strongly typed language. Neither Java nor C++ would allow this

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile because `WriteLine` is missing. Post the *actual* code. Something people can copy and try to compile

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Note the `using static System.Console;`

Comment: @MatthewWatson at the wrong snippet. I did guess that was involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you mean is called duck-typing and some languages like Go use that: If it walks like a duck, it must be a duck, right? C# does not support that, though. Instead, you need to explicitly implement the interface. The compiler is warning you about this by not allowing the implicit conversion. By using an explicit conversion, you are basically telling the compiler "Shut up, I know what I'm doing", and hence, the compiler shuts up and trusts you.